# UITableViewCell has wrong height when adding custom view from xib as a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I have UITableView with cells and within each of the cells I want to add custom view. I created xib file MyView.xib and I created class that is extension of UIView class and has the name MyView. In the xib file I added File's Owner class to be MyView.

When adding this custom view within UITableViewCell I want that custom view to have dynamic height. That is why I added this code within init method.

```
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

        if (self) {

        // 1. load the interface
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
        // 2. add as subview
        [self addSubview:self.view];
        // 3. allow for autolayout
        [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        // 4. add constraints to span entire view
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":self.view}]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":self.view}]];

        [self setStyle];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Important note is that I am using storyboard for creating tableView. So I have table view with one Prototype Cells and I am adding my custom view with other content here. And I am using auto layout.

Now the problem is when I run the app first few visible cell have wrong height (custom view is not completely visible). When I scroll down next cells have good height (custom view is visible) and when I scroll back after that the hight of the few cell at the top of the list is correct.

Can someone told me how to fix this problem with height of the cells when loading list for the first time?

Comment: Move it to the `awakeFromNib` func instead

Comment: @CZ54 Doesn't make any difference. :/

Comment: may be your cell is reuse.

Comment: Try calling `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` before you return cell in `cellForRow`

Comment: @Tj3n Already tried that and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // 1. load the interface
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
    // 2. add as subview
    [self addSubview:self.view];
    // 3. allow for autolayout
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    // 4. add constraints to span entire view
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":self.view}]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":self.view}]];

    [self setStyle];
}
```